# Cannot enable a section in profile System Administrator

Tags: permissions, profile, permission-sets, system-admin

Run Flows

I cannot check these box in the profile System administrator..Should I use permission sets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot edit the permissions on system Administrator profile as it is  Standard and Read-only. If you which to give any permissions you may need to use the Permission sets and if you want to restrict any permissions you may need to clone the profile and use the cloned profile.

But I guess Most of the permissions should be enabled by default for the system Administrator. Even though if they are not enabled their superior permissions might have be enabled like Run Flows is not enabled because Manage flows is already enabled.

But if you want to give any permissions for the System Administrator  you may need to create a permission set and assign to the users.

Comment: IN that case I will have to check each for the system admin right if I can perform the particular action for that particular profile.In case of report builder I have to try creating editing reports right

Comment: The Report Builder permission gives the user the ability to "Create, edit, and delete reports through the drag-and-drop report builder interface.

Comment: Check the below link for [Report Builder ](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/reports_dashboards/reports_dashboards_getting_started ) [Einstein Search Demo] (https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.search_einstein.htm&type=5)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new profile. Clone the standard System Administrator profile.